# return a not null variable from a set of variables like in javascript

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to get a non-null variable from a set of variables, like in JavaScript:

```
var 
  aNullVar = null,
  normalVariable = {},
  aNotNullVar = aNullVar || normalVariable;
// aNotNullVar is a Object {}
```

I tried to do the same in PHP, but it returns a boolean:

```
$aNullVar = null;
$normalVariable = new stdClass();
$aNotNullVar = $aNullVar || $normalVariable;
// var_dump of $aNotNullVar gives bool(true)
```

P.S. I dont want to use `if` checks or `ternary operations`

Comment: What should it do, when there are only NULL variables?

Comment: @Rizier123 JavaScript returns null

Comment: The `bool(true)` you get proves the the OR condition you wrote turned out to be true. No it's not possible without `if`s.

Comment: The syntax you want to use, does not work the same way in PHP. You have to use either if or ternary

Comment: If I have 10s of variables it would be very messy

Comment: Use foreach then to iterate over a set of vars.

Comment: `$aNotNullVar = $aNullVar ?: $normalVariable;`

Comment: @Yoshi he doesnt want ternary operations

Comment: @roullie Maybe only because he/she does not know of this particular way of writing it? Let's see.

Comment: @Yoshi your solution would be proper one if I had only two variables

Comment: @zazu Why? `$foo = $a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d;` would work just fine, while being just as messy as it's javascript counterpart.

Comment: @Yoshi that is much better, however if I have a `false` value at first, it simply skips it

Comment: @zazu Wouldn't JS do the same? Both solutions will return the first *non-falsy* value.

Comment: @Yoshi right, I didnt think about it. anyway solution I have come to is better for getting first non-null variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found a solution. I had to create the following function:

```
function notNull($var)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $arg)
    {
        if($arg !== null)
            return $arg;
    }
    return null;
}
```